# How to correct my code to see small size widget on my top left of my screen?

Tags: c++, qt

I started to learn C++ and Qt with a beginner's book. After reading some of them(about 10%), I wrote a code that just create my first simple widget on my laptop screen. In my theory using setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 50), I could see the small size widget on top left of my screen. But when I run the code, big size widget come out from middle of my screen. What is heppening. How to correct my code to see small size widget on my top left of my screen?

Here is my c++ code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

class MyWidget : public QWidget{
  QWidget w;
public:
  MyWidget();
};

MyWidget::MyWidget(){
  w.setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 50);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MyWidget mw;
  mw.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new `QWidget w;` inside your `MyWidget` class which you shouldn't need.  Remove that and change your constructor code to:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(){
  setGeometry(0, 0, 50, 50); // calls function on *this*
};
```

In your original code `setGeometry` was not being applied to the correct `MyWidget` object, but rather the instance `w` of your `MyWidget` which is not shown.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. I appreciate you.